# What is implied by the Tribhanga form of God or Goddess?

Tags: krishna, goddess, symbolism, durga

[image]

Lord Sri Krishna is known as 'Tribhanga MurAri', as shown in the enclosed image. As per the Dhyana-Mantra of Goddess Durga, She is also having a Tribhanga form.

What exactly is meant or signified by Tribhanga according to the scriptures?

Comment: The meaning is the three-bends of the appearance right. Are you looking for a spiritual meaning?

Comment: @user1952500 yes and exactly which parts of the body shd bend